# Выделение сравнительного оборота на письме

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

"Дмитрий вел себя как ребенок".

Перед *как* нужна запятая? Или этот оборот приближается к обстоятельству?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае оборот тесно связан со сказуемом и не отделяется запятой.
**Ср.: Он выглядел как человек больной; В баснях звери ведут себя как люди; ведёт себя как невменяемый.**